# Presta Accessing Products before addToCart

Tags: ajax, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.7

In Presta 1.6 there was the possibility to use the JS ajaxCart Object to add ajax functions to alter your products before they are appended to the Cart. I am trying to rediscover such an ability in Presta 1.7 where apparently the ajaxCart Object is no longer defined.

Unfortunately I do not have code or anything to show, I simply would need to know whether there is a proper way now, a hook or anything, to modify your products before adding them to the Cart?

If there is no proper way, I would also be thankful for improper ways. Did the ajaxCart Object get a different scope? Was it replaced by another mechanism? Unfortunately I did not succeed a whole lot in reverse engineering the changed.